# IndexOutOfBoundsException in TabLayout in android support design lib

Tags: java, android, android-support-design

I use [android.support.design](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design) in all my projects, and today I updated it to latest version

com.android.support:design:22.2.1

It was a bad idea, because my project crashed with

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.getTabAt(TabLayout.java:407)
android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:585)
```

After some debugging, I found a problem in this method:

```
 public void setupWithViewPager(@NonNull ViewPager viewPager) {
    PagerAdapter adapter = viewPager.getAdapter();
    if(adapter == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ViewPager does not have a PagerAdapter set");
    } else {
        this.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(this));
        this.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));
        if(this.mSelectedTab == null || this.mSelectedTab.getPosition() != viewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
            this.getTabAt(viewPager.getCurrentItem()).select();// ERROR On my code I'm used empty adapter 
        }

    }
}
```

But in previous version 22.2.0 of lib, all was  working fine:

```
    public void setupWithViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    PagerAdapter adapter = viewPager.getAdapter();
    if(adapter == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ViewPager does not have a PagerAdapter set");
    } else {
        this.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(this));
        this.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));
    }
}
```

Who did it and who can be punished for it?

Please help me find developers for Android support Design library.

Comment: from what I see, I feel `viewPager.getCurrentItem()` is not **zero-indexed** and the method, `getTabAt()` expects it to be. Check the APIs, try `this.getTabAt(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1).select();`

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary: `getCurrentItem()` on `ViewPager` is zero-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd love to just comment with this, but I don't have the reputation.

It looks like this issue is being tracked and pegged for a fix in a future release: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180453

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that your problem is due to:

```
// ERROR On my code I'm used empty adapter
```

Apparently, `TabLayout` does not like empty adapters. This does not surprise me.

So, do not call `setupWithViewPager()` right away. When you do eventually update your `PagerAdapter` to return a non-zero value from `getCount()`, you can call `setupWithViewPager()`. Second and subsequent times you change the `PagerAdapter`, after calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter, call `setTabsFromPagerAdapter()` to refresh the tabs to align with the `PagerAdapter` contents. You can use a `boolean` to track whether you need to call `setupWithViewPager()` or `setTabsFromPagerAdapter()`.

You are certainly welcome to [file a feature request](http://b.android.com) for `TabLayout` to support empty adapters.

Comment: This answer is great, it makes sense and it does fix the problem. I am very surprised the the other one which should actually be deleted was accepted.